# Should I add web libraries as git submodules for a project?

Tags: jquery, git, version-control, heroku, twitter-bootstrap

For example, if my web application uses *jQuery* and *Twitter Bootstrap*, would it be a better option to:

1. Just commit minified, compiled, "final" files and change as new versions are released.
2. Add both the projects as git submodules and build them alongside the application.

Also, please indicate why a particular option is better according to you. I think adding them as git submodules and building them would be the right thing to do, but this approach tends to cause problems with Heroku (I don't need the entire repo, just the built files for the application to work!)

Answer (score 1):

Are you deploing Rails 3.1 / 3.2 ?

If so, just go for [twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) and you'll get it out of the box.
That's the better way to support Rails pipelining too, with Bootstrap 2.0 / 2.0.1, as well as the best way to stay up-to-date and [upgrading](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/wiki/Upgrading-Guide).

Comment: and then use the asset pipeline and asset_sync gem to gem them hosted outside of Heroku so your application doesn't have to serve the static assets

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might make up your mind is the support level for Git Submodules:

> Git submodules are now supported as a Heroku Labs feature.
>   http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules

I would use submodules if possible as it means you've got an easy update path if you need it, however, as submodules is still in the early stages of support @ Heroku this might turn you off it.